# How to create and manage a new DCOM object via batch or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, batch, dcom

Win+R. dcomcnfg > I need to register a new dll using this tool as a COM. I can do this manually. But I have a lot of WS.

regsvr32 is not enough. The COM App need to exist in dcomcnfg

So, can it be done via batch or Powershell so I could distribute script using GPO? I didn't find any useful info about that problem.

Comment: I found this article which may be related to your issue and help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807865/dcomcnfg-why-doesnt-dll-show-up .

Comment: I would like to add as well if you install it via the conventional method in comexp.msc then you can export the application for install on other systems as an MSI which may be able to be installed in the method you prefer.

Comment: @philipenix How do I export the application? I'm unable to find that feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the export option. You'll need to import/register the application first as noted in the comments.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I clicked on the adjacent icon which didn't contain export option and assumed the export function was elsewhere.